# How-to build a directive to customize labelized radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is a custom radio buttons:

[image]

The angular HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="ctrl" class="sm-box">
      <p>Please select a mode:
      <sm-radio model="mode" value="MODE1" label="One" ng-click='mode="MODE1"'></sm-radio>
      <sm-radio model="mode" value="MODE2" label="Two"></sm-radio>
      <sm-radio model="mode" value="MODE3" label="Three"></sm-radio></p>
      <p>Selected mode is: {{mode}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The corresponding JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ) {
   $scope.mode = 'MODE1';
}]);

app.directive('smRadio',  ['$compile', function($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: function( tElt, tAttrs ) {
         tElt.addClass( 'sm-radio' );
         tElt.append(
            '<input type="radio"' +
            ' name="'     + tAttrs.model + '"' +
            ' ng-model="' + tAttrs.model + '"' +
            ' value="'    + tAttrs.value + '"' +
            ' /><label>'  + tAttrs.label + '</label>'
         );
         if( ! tElt.attr('ng-click')) {
            // This is a first try
            tElt.attr('ng-click', 'mode="' + tAttrs.value + '"' );
            // this is a variant
            tElt.ngClick = 'mode="' + tAttrs.value + '"';
            // None has effect...
            $compile(tElt); // compilation here had twice elements!!!
         }
      }
   };
}]);
```

The problem is "One" is clickable and sets the model "mode" to "MODE1" but "Two" and "Three" are not, only the radio buttons may select "MODE2" or "MODE3".

As you can see in the HTML source, the first have "ng-click" attribute when the other have not. I'm trying to add "ng-click" attribute in my directive, by code but I'm unsuccessful.

**How can I add "ng-click" attribute in a directive?**

**EDIT**: Answers guide to not use ng-click at all, so title has been updated

Comment: I think you'll need to use $compile on tElt.  If you add in DOM from the javascript side, angular doesn't know about it.  Which is why $compile is needed to bind it to the scope.

Comment: I have tried to compile but the effect is tricky: twice elements added and no click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is exactly what I want, largely inspired by [tomek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30855153/1624376) answer, simplified and the idea of `label` in place of `div` of [Ervald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30855558/1624376) answer.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ) {
   $scope.xmode = 'MODE2';
   $scope.ymode = 'MODE_B';
}]);

app.directive('smRadio', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope   : {
         model: '=',
         value: '@',
         label: '@'
      },
      template:
         '<label class="sm-radio"' +
         ' ng-model="model">' +
         '<input type="radio" name="{{model}}"' +
         ' ng-model="model"' +
         ' ng-value="value"' +
         ' ng-checked="model==value"> {{label}}</label>'
   };
});
```

```css
.sm-box {
   background-color: lightgray;
   border          : solid 1px;
   padding         : 4px;
   width           : 500px;
}
.sm-radio {
   background-color: lightblue;
   color           : #fff;
   display         : inline-block;
   border          : 1px solid darkgray;
   border-radius   : 8px;
   padding         : 8px;
}
.sm-radio>input {
   width         : 24px;
   height        : 24px;
   vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="ctrl" class="sm-box">
      <p>Please select a Xmode:
      <sm-radio model="xmode" value="MODE1" label="One"></sm-radio>
      <sm-radio model="xmode" value="MODE2" label="Two"></sm-radio>
      <sm-radio model="xmode" value="MODE3" label="Three"></sm-radio></p>
      <p>Selected mode is: {{xmode}}</p>
      <p>Please select a Ymode:
      <sm-radio model="ymode" value="MODE_A" label="A"></sm-radio>
      <sm-radio model="ymode" value="MODE_B" label="B"></sm-radio>
      <sm-radio model="ymode" value="MODE_C" label="C"></sm-radio></p>
      <p>Selected mode is: {{ymode}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: Two independent buttons groups]

Answer (score 1):

It is considered best practice to pass values to directive from "outside world" by using isolated scope. As you can see, it makes it easier too:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ) {
   $scope.mode = 'MODE1';
}]);

app.directive('smRadio', function($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        model: '=',
        value: '@',
        label: '@'
      },

      template: '' +
        '<input type="radio" name="name" ng-model="model" value="value"' +
        ' ng-checked="model==value" ng-click="model=value">' +
        '<label ng-click="model=value">{{label}}</label>',

      compile: function(tElt) {
         tElt.addClass( 'sm-radio' );
      }
   };
});
```

Here's working example: http://jsbin.com/fejori/3/edit?js,output

(In case of this much code in 'template' attribute of a directive, I'd move it to outside html file and link it instead by using `templateUrl` attribute)

Comment: Thank's. Can you set ng-click on the sm-radio element in place of label?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to encapsulate this functionality **inside** the directive you can set it **on** the directive itself. You can then ommit `ng-click` on both `<input>` and `<label>` elements inside.

Comment: JSBin gave an error when I tried to run the provided example:


    "error"
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.29.8.min.js:1:13603
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.29.8.min.js:1:10524"
    "error"
    "Script error. (line 0)"

I would like to test it out also - - thanks in advance...

Comment: @ClaireW sorry, my fault, must have changed something before saving. If's fixed now: http://jsbin.com/fejori/3/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

Here's doing it without `ng-click`. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14244/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.modes = [
        {label: 'MODE 1', value: 1 },
        {label: 'MODE 2', value: 2},
        {label: 'MODE 3', value: 3}
    ];

    $scope.selected = 2;
}]);

app.directive('smRadio', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {model: '=', selected: '='},
      template: function( tElt, tAttrs ) {
          return '<label ng-repeat="radio in model"><input type="radio" ng-value="radio.value" name="modes" ng-model="selected" ng-change="change(radio.value)">{{radio.label}}</label>';
      },
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
           scope.change = function(val){
               scope.selected = val;
           }
       }
   };
});
```

Comment: I prefer to put view stuff like labels in HTML and behaviors into controllers. Values are `{MODE1, MODE2, MODE3}` and labels are `{'One','Two', 'Three'}`. The whole `div` has to be clickable.

Comment: I just tried the fiddle:  +1 for the clickable label!